# Remove a character from every item of a list in JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

I have a string like this `"-FOREST&-JUNGLE&DESERT"`
This string is split up into words in a list like so: `[-FOREST, -JUNGLE ,DESERT]`
`List<String> pattern = Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s*&\\s*"));`

Every word with a minus at the beginning must be in one new list and every word without in another like so:

```
List<String> allowedtags = pattern
                            .stream()
                            .filter(name -> !name.startsWith("-"))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<String> unwantedtags = pattern
                            .stream()
                            .filter(name -> name.startsWith("-"))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My problem is that my `unwantedtags` keeps words with a minus at the beginning, but for all my operations I need to get rid of it. If I do the example below, it will not work if "FOREST" is in `taglist` as my `unwantedtags` contains "-FOREST".

```
if (taglist.stream().anyMatch(unwantedtags::contains)) {
                        return !IsWhitelist;
                        }
```

So how can I fix my unwantedtags list? Maybe in java 8 stream api?
Moreover I have the feeling that on the one hand it is working fine to that point, but on the other hand I get the feeling that this is a lot of code for getting just two lists. Can it be optimized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map each element to strip out the leading minus sign after it has been detected:

```
List<String> unwantedtags = pattern
                            .stream()
                            .filter(name -> name.startsWith("-"))
                            .map(name -> name.substring(1))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The code can be made more efficient by constructing and populating the lists explicitly. Then you can process `pattern` in a single pass instead of two:

```
List<String> allowedtags = new ArrayList();
List<String> unwantedtags = new ArrayList();
pattern.stream()
       .forEach(name -> {
                if (name.startsWith("-")) unwantedtags.add(name.substring(1));
                else allowedtags.add(name);
            }
        );
```

Comment: If I add your single pass I get "bad return type in lambda expression: boolean can not be converted to void.

Comment: @ErikSteiner - Yeah, my lambda syntax was wrong. I fixed it to something that works.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a single Operation. With the map() Operator you can take the input string and modify it.

```
List<String> unwantedtags = pattern
                .stream()
                .filter(name -> name.startsWith("-"))
                .map(name -> name.substring(1))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupingBy` to divide this collection (by `name.startsWith("-")`):

```java
Map<Boolean, List<String>> collect = pattern.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(name -> name.startsWith("-")));
```

Then you have:

```
{false=[DESERT], true=[-FOREST, -JUNGLE]}
```

After that you can do further processing (with `unwantedtags`):

```java
List<String> unwantedtags = collect
        .getOrDefault(true, List.of()).stream()
        .map(name -> name.substring(1))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or you can do it in one stream but it can look more complicated.

```java
Map<Boolean, List<String>> collectWithMap = pattern.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(name -> name.startsWith("-"),
                Collectors.mapping(name -> name.startsWith("-") ? name.substring(1) : name, 
                        Collectors.toList())));
```

result:

```
{false=[DESERT], true=[FOREST, JUNGLE]}
```